# Sitecore SOLR results with highlights

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

(my ultimate goal is to have my search results page much like Google - facets, categories, synonyms, spelling corrections, and highlighting - but I'm working on highlighting first)

I followed the instructions on [How to Highlight Search Terms Using ContentSearch in Sitecore With Solr](http://www.cmsbestpractices.com/highlight-search-terms-using-contentsearch-sitecore-solr/) to get results, but I'm not sure what to do with the results. The code example looks like:

```cs
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext(SearchSecurityOptions.DisableSecurityCheck))
{
    var result = context.GetExtendedQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(it => it["content_t"] == "panda").GetResultsWithHighlights("content_t", "title_t");
    var highlights = result.Highlights;
}
```

When I run the commands in SOLR, I see the response contains a `<result>` element, having a number of `<doc>` elements, but the highlighted texts are separate and in a `<lst name="highlighting">` element. This also seems to be true on on the C# side - `result` has both `result.Results` and `result.Highlights`.

The `result.Highlights` only contains highlighted fragments, and does not contain fields that are not matched. The search results page should list the `title_t` (highlighting the search string if it exists), and below the title, the `content_t` fragment (highlighting the search string if it exists). If `content_t` doesn't have a relevant fragment, then I want to pull the `Description` field from the Sitecore item. How do I "tie" the `result.Results` with the `result.Highlights` with the Sitecore item to achieve the display?